# telegram mtproto/core how to comment on a post in the channel

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, mtproto

I want to comment on a post in one of the channels I joined through a user both using the package "@mtproto/core", but I can't do it in any way.

But I still didn't understand what data I need to transfer to Params and where to get it from

I have tried these two methods:
https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage
https://core.telegram.org/constructor/messageReplyHeader

my code example:

```
import MTProto from "@mtproto/core";
import path from "path";

const proto = new MTProto({
    api_id: proccess.env.API_ID,
    api_hash: proccess.env.API_HASH,

    storageOptions: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './data/1.json'),
    },
});

async function init(params, options) {
    try {
        const res = await proto.call("messageReplies", params, options);
        console.log(res);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
};
init(
    {
        message: "Test",
        reply_to_msg_id: 7,
        forum_topic: -1762531849,
        silent: true,
    },
    {
    }
);
```